# Compare and sort based on overlap

Tags: matlab, sorting, find, compare

I have a cell array that looks like this (truncated):

```
'State Name'                   'State Abbr'    'State Code'    'Region'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
'Alabama'                      'AL'            '01'            '04'
'Alaska'                       'AK'            '02'            '10'
'Arizona'                      'AZ'            '04'            '09'
'Arkansas'                     'AR'            '05'            '06'
'California'                   'CA'            '06'            '09'
'Canada'                       'CC'            'CC'            '25'
'Colorado'                     'CO'            '08'            '08'
'Connecticut'                  'CT'            '09'            '01'
'Country Of Mexico'            'MX'            '80'            '25'
'Delaware'                     'DE'            '10'            '03'
'Delaware'                     'DE'            '10'            '03'
'Florida'                      'FL'            '12'            '04'
'Georgia'                      'GA'            '13'            '04'
```

I have another array that looks like this (truncated):

```
      MonitorID         POC    Latitude    Longitude     Datum           ParameterName           SampleDuration
___________________    ___    ________    _________    _______    __________________________    _______________

'01-073-0023-88101'    '1'    33.553      -86.815      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'01-073-0023-88101'    '1'    33.553      -86.815      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'01-073-0023-88101'    '1'    33.553      -86.815      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'01-073-0023-88101'    '1'    33.553      -86.815      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'01-073-0023-88101'    '1'    33.553      -86.815      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
'02-170-0013-88101'    '1'    61.599      -149.46      'WGS84'    'PM2.5 - Local Conditions'    '24 HOUR'
```

What I would like to do is to sort the second array (which actually has a lot more rows and columns) by the region code from the first array.

Right now, the second array does have the region code. However, it does have the state code. The state code is the first two numbers in the `MonitorID` column. For example, for '01-073-0023-88101', the state code is '01'. I need to find each state code in the second array and match it to the correct region given in the first array. Then, I need to sort the second array by the region code.

How can I do this? I'm not sure how I can compare the first two numbers from the second array to the 3rd column of the first array and assign new region to it. Sorting it shouldn't be too difficult once those steps are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `A` and `B` to be the first and second arrays respectively, this would be one approach -

```
%// Split the first column of B with "-" as the delimiter
Bcol1_split = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,'-'),B(:,1),'Uni',0)

%// Extract the first split string which would be the state codes
Bcol1_first_string = cellfun(@(x) x{1},Bcol1_split,'Uni',0)

%// Detect IDs of matching state codes from from B to those in A 
[~,matched_ID] = ismember(Bcol1_first_string,A(:,3))

%// Use those IDs to get corresponding Region codes for each row of data in B
mapped_region_codes = A(matched_ID,4)

%// Sort the region codes to get the IDs based on which B is to be
%// row-indexed, which would be the final output
[~,sorted_mapped_IDs] =  sort(mapped_region_codes)
outB = B(sorted_mapped_IDs,:)
```

Comment: Pretty much what I would have done, but I used regular expressions instead lol. +1.